# how to handle date format using to_date function in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, to-date

I have a select query that consist an expression of `TO_DATE(expiry_date, 'YYMM')`.

It works if `expiry_date` is in `YYMM` format.
I want to set data as `0001` if `expiry_date` is in incorrect formats that are like `YYM`, `YY`,`MM`,`YMM` etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: How can you tell if its `YYM` or `YMM` ?

Comment: It's not important. 3 digit format is incorrect anyway.

Comment: Indeed, but it requires different handling. How would you know *which* way to go ?

Comment: `I want to set data as 0100`. Sorry, you wont be able to do that, because month cannot be `00` - should be `from 01 to 12`. So you have to pick another substitution value.

Comment: I dont really know which way to go. Please I need really help.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I edited. in YYMM format (so I mean 01.01.2000) the correct date is `0001`

Comment: How would you stop the dummy data being treated as a real date later - how can you distinguish, or does that not matter either? Can you use `null` if it's invalid, as a slightly more palatable magic value? Also, if your data is that bad (as happens when storing structured data as strings), what will you do with `'1113'`, say, or anything else that will throw an exception on conversion? And more generally, how do you know if `'1112'` was meant to be December 2011 or November 2012?

Comment: @AlexPoole you are right, i need to add an exception for datas like `1113`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is ugly, but seems to do the trick:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT '123' AS val FROM dual
  UNION SELECT '12' FROM dual
  UNION SELECT '1' FROM dual
  UNION SELECT '12345' FROM dual
  UNION SELECT '9612' FROM dual -- ok
  UNION SELECT '9613' FROM dual -- wrong
  UNION SELECT '1296' FROM dual -- wrong
  UNION SELECT 'AAAA' FROM dual -- wrong
)
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN length(val) != 4
      OR NOT regexp_like(val, '[0-9]{4}')
      OR NOT to_number(substr(val, 3, 2)) BETWEEN 1 AND 12
    THEN to_date('0010', 'YYMM')
    ELSE to_date(val, 'YYMM')
  END AS date_yymm
FROM data;
```

Output:

```
DATE_YYMM
----------
01-10-2000
01-10-2000
01-10-2000
01-10-2000
01-10-2000
01-12-2096
01-10-2000
01-10-2000
```

Or you can just use a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_date_format(p_value IN VARCHAR2, p_format IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER
AS
  l_dummy DATE;
BEGIN
  l_dummy := to_date(p_value, p_format);
  RETURN 0;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 1;
END;
/

WITH data AS (
  SELECT '123' AS val FROM dual
  UNION SELECT '12' FROM dual
  UNION SELECT '1' FROM dual
  UNION SELECT '12345' FROM dual
  UNION SELECT '9612' FROM dual -- ok
  UNION SELECT '9613' FROM dual -- wrong
  UNION SELECT '1296' FROM dual -- wrong
)
SELECT
  -- fx for exact matching as pointed out by Nicholas Krasnov
  DECODE(is_date_format(val, 'fxYYMM'), 0, val, '0010')
FROM data;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  CASE
            WHEN LENGTH(expiry_date) = 4
            THEN TO_DATE(expiry_date, 'YYMM')
            ELSE TO_DATE('0001', 'YYMM')
        END AS d_date
FROM
(
        SELECT 1212 expiry_date FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 1211             FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 1210             FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 121              FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 12               FROM DUAL
)
;
/*
2012-12-01 00:00:00
2012-11-01 00:00:00
2012-10-01 00:00:00
2000-01-01 00:00:00
2000-01-01 00:00:00
*/
```

Something like this?